# Copy file1 to file2 except the final byte in 1 command

Tags: dd, copy

I need to find out how I could copy a file1 to a file2 except the last byte. I've been looking around and came on the dd command but the skip option only allows to skip at the start of the input file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using `head -c`:

```
   -c, --bytes=[-]NUM
          print  the  first  NUM bytes of each file; with the leading '-',
          print all but the last NUM bytes of each file
```

So

```
head -c -1 file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived from an answer posted on ["How do I chop off just the last byte of a file in Bash?" on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-chop-off-just-the-last-byte-of-a-file-in-Bash):

`dd if=file1 of=file2 bs=1 count=$(( $( find file1 -printf '%s' ) - 1 ))`

Or...

`dd if=file1 of=file2 bs=1 count=$(( $( stat -c%s file1 ) - 1 ))`

However, `head -c` as stated in the other answer is the easier solution.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to prefer `find` over, say, `wc -c < file1` ?

Comment: or `stat -c%s file1`...

Comment: @ByteCommander in place of find, you mean.